# Scramble a string Perl

Tags: perl, substring, reverse

I am using substring and reverse in order to scramble a string. But my solution was tedious to write and there must be a much smoother way. Allegedly this should be able to work with only two variables using substring and reverse? But how? The substring only removes the letters that I want, and discards the rest of the string. Appreciate any input.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$string = mystring;
$name = substr($string, 0, 2);
$name = reverse($name);
$name1 = substr($string, 2, 4);
$name2 = substr($string, 6, 8);
$name2 = reverse($name2);
print uc($name);
print uc($name1);
print uc($name2);
```

Comment: What did you mean to write here? The third parameter of `substr` is the *length* of the substring, so `substr($string, 6, 8)` is asking for the seventh to the fourteenth characters, yet your string is only eight characters long

Answer (score 1):

You could use the  [`shuffle()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#@values-=-shuffle-@values) function from [`List::Util`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#NAME).

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

use List::Util qw(shuffle);

my $string = 'mystring';
my $shuffled_string = join '', shuffle(split //, $string);
# 'nmyisgrt'
```

Comment: I actually like your solution to use `shuffle`. I personally would have used a few more lines just to make things clearer, but `shuffle` is self explanatory on what you're doing . I assume the down vote happened because the OP stated they want to use `substr` and `reverse`.

Comment: @DavidW. Fair point about `substr` and `reverse`, I was looking at it from the point of view that as long as the string is shuffled the implementation doesn't matter.

Comment: The OP is asking for *“a much smoother way”*. They also say *“Allegedly this should be able to work with only two variables using substring and reverse? But how?”*. How can you assume that they just want to mess the string up somehow? Your suggestion of using `shuffle` is irreversible, so you may as well write `my $shuffled_string = 'abcdefgh'`

Comment: The OP's initial post wasn't clear. The OP never responded to any questions on their post. Maybe the OP was making a word scramble. Maybe this was a homework assignment. Maybe the string had to be scrambled in a particular fashion or with particular commands. We don't know. Using a command called `shuffle` to _scramble_ a string is an elegant solution. Using a readily available Perl module (and a standard one too) is even better. We just don't know if it did or didn't meet the OP's criteria.

Comment: @Borodin The title is what led me to this implementation. If there were any indications that the process needed to be reversible, then my solution would have been different. As David W mentions, it is hard to determine what is/was needed with no feedback from the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
my $string = 'mystring';
$string =~ s/^(..)(....)(.+)$/reverse($1) . $2 . reverse($3)/e;
print uc($string),"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
YMSTRIGN
```

We substitute the original string with the first two characters reversed, the 4 following are keep as is and the rest is also reversed.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind explaining what's going on here?

Comment: `.{1,}` is generally written `.+`

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'My string is a good string';

for my $i (0 .. length($string)/2) {
    substr($string, $i * 2, 2) = uc reverse substr($string, $i * 2, 2);
}

print "$string\n";
```

Output:

```
YMS RTNI GSIA G OO DTSIRGN
```